# Tracking MUC room list with XMPP (ejabberd)

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, multiuserchat

I'd like to allow a client to keep track of the list of rooms on a multi-user chat service provided by ejabberd.  This would require receiving notifications of room creation/destruction and presence events for all rooms on the server.

Is there a way to subscribe to receive notifications about such events without sending a presence event to, and therefore joining the roster of all rooms?

FWIW, I've found out how to send a request for the room list (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-rooms) and I've been trying to make sense of the pubsub system (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#glossary) in hope that I'd find a solution there but nothing seems obvious.

What's the right(TM) way to do this in XMPP land?

Ubuntu 10.04 + ejabberd 2.1.5-3+squeeze1  + Strophe.js & BOSH & jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop custom code for that, especially to trigger packets sending on the event you are interested.